# How to make a Qt QML variable accessible anywhere

Tags: qt, qml

I would like to have a qt QML var accessible globally, and anywhere else in my qml files. Is this possible?

I know that upon creating a variable in a C++ object can be accessed in QML by exposing its getter function, but this only works if you know the type of the data type e.g. string, int, bool.

Is there a variable data type (or class) that can handle a QML var in C++, so that I can only call it in the other parts of the QML files?

Comment: Do you know about the `rootContext`? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html#setting-an-object-as-a-context-property

Comment: isnt that the one responsible for exposing the c++ functions to QML . What i need though is a C++ variable that can hold a VAR data type, for me to be able to access it everywhere.

Comment: Please explain what you try to achive. Do you need to modifiy this variable from QML? Ist it really a variable or a constant?

Comment: @Jack no, this is to expose objects. And as far as I understand you are looking for a `QVariant`, which you can achieve with the answer from @derM. Theoretically you could skip the encapsulation in a `QObject` but then you don't have the `myVarChanged` notification

Answer (score 1):

AS Amfasis said, you can use the rootContext, so you can access it from anywhere in QML - as long as you do not shadow the name. Alternatively you can also register a Singleton to QML.
For both, you first need to create a QObject

```
public class MyContextObject: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QVariant myVar READ myVar NOTIFY myVarChanged)

    QVariant m_myVar;
public:
    MyContextObject(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}

    QVariant myVar() { return m_myVar; }

    void setMyVar(QVariant var) { 
        if (var == m_myVar) return;
        m_myVar = var;
        emit myVarChanged();
    }

signals:
    void myVarChanged();
}
```

This object you create in your *main* and set it as a `contextProperty`

```
MyContextObject* mctx = new MyContextObject();
view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myCtx", mctx);
```

To set it from C++ use the setter. On the QML-side just bind to `myCtx.myVar`
Expose the setter also, if you want to modify it from QML also

---

> This is not tested, I don't have a Qt development environment available right now.
>   To expose it as singleton, you can use this function:
>   https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType-1

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, i will investigate it and mark it as answer when i am able to confirm it